# Killing GSM Buzz with Ferrite Beads

Tags: interference, gsm

I'm trying to rid my speakers of the typical buzz from my iPhone. I get poor reception in my apartment and so it's constantly trying to find a signal, meaning I get a near-constant buzzing when the phone's anywhere near it. Airplane Mode works, but it's a pain to keep switching it on or off.

I use reference monitors as opposed to ordinary speakers, and each has an audio output cable (XLR, balanced), and a mains output (i.e. each speaker is powered independently). Do I need cores for all four cables, just the audio output, just the mains? If so, do they need to wrap TIGHTLY around the cables, or if they're loose and I secure them with tape, is it the presence of the cables that suppresses the noise?

Comment: I am confused where your noise is coming from. Do your reference monitors have the noise on them, or is it what ever your XLR and mains output are running to that has the noise?

Answer (score 6):

The interference comes from GSM being a time division technology and the transmitter being switched on and off quickly. Poorly designed amplifiers can unintentionally receive this signal and convert it to an audible signal. The problem could also be in the signal source.

The principle behind [ferrite beads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrite_bead) removing the interference is that they would create a high impedance for the RF signal to get to the audio amplifier. The easy way to find out if your problem is with mains (or the amplifier internals in the speaker) or audio signal cables is to disconnect the audio input. If you still get the noise with only mains connected and speakers powered, the problem cannot be fixed with ferrites on the audio cable.

I won't repeat the use information from the wikipedia page so take a look at that if you didn't.

To purposefully induce the noise for testing your filtering, you can for example call yourself - it will signal the network even though the call will not likely be connected. Try moving the phone close to the audio signal cable, the speaker itself and the signal source to find out where your set up is most vulnerable.

Comment: As a note, poorly designed phones can also cause this problem. Many phones will go cheap on their decoupling capacitors next to their power amps and because of the burstyness of time division, they can actually cause the load on the power lines to drop the voltage a significant amount. This can cause some radiation that a sound system could pick up even if it wouldn't have picked up the intentional radiation.

Comment: If there is an option to force the phone to WCDMA or CDMA, the problem will usually go away since there is no similar switching of the transmitter. Unfortunately the iPhone cannot be forced 3G only and often when GSM coverage is bad, 3G is non-existent.